# Mocha unit test throw Timeout of 3000ms exceeded

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mocha.js

i wanted to add a delay between two tests because one it depends on another

all's good except when i change params to test catch it only shows this error

```
Error: Timeout of 3000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

test code

```
it('save Prods', function(done){

        this.timeout(3000); 

        setTimeout(() => {
           graphql.saveProd.resolve(null,
                {
                    prod_id : prod_id,
                })
                .then(data => {

                        expect(data).to.be.an('array')
                        done()

                }).catch(done) <----- as you see here i added done() in both cases (then & catch)

            },3000)
    })
```

Comment: Can you this with async/await?

Comment: @KarthickRam just tested it , not working it supposed to be it shows '1 passing' and after it shows the error ...  1 passing (104ms)
  45 pending

3
[bugsnag] Reported an unhandled rejection…
FORBIDDEN <---- the error